# CURL name of the source file = name of the target file

Tags: curl

I want to download a lot of files which have all similar names: `xxx/1.jpg`, `xxx/2.jpg`, `xxx/3.jpg`, and so on to `C:/Brawa/`.
So I write:

```
CURL https://example/xxx/[1-3].jpg -o C:/Brawa/#1.jpg
```

Now I want the name of the source file to correspond with the name of the target file: `C:/Brawa/xxx/1.jpg`; `C:/Brawa/xxx/2.jpg`; `C:/Brawa/xxx/3.jpg`, and so on.

I use the command-line:

```
CURL https://example/xxx/[1-3].jpg -o --remote-name C:/Brawa/*.jpg
```

Something does not work, but what did I make wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
CURL https://example/xxx/[1-3].jpg -o --remote-name C:/Brawa/#1.jpg
```

Comment: It does not work with this command line. I got the message
curl: (1) Protocol "C" not supported or disabled in libcurl I read (https://curl.se/docs/faq.html#Protocol_xxx_not_supported_or_di) but do not understand it.
If I write

CURL https://xxx[1-3].jpg --remote-name -o C:/Brawa/#1.jpg

it works but saves the file in C:/User/…..

Comment: It might picking up the C from the parameter, so try quoting it. Try also using backward slashes (\\) instead of forward (/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using an up-to-date version of `curl` (version 7.73.0 or higher), you should be able to add the new `--output-dir` option to specify an output directory e.g.:

```
curl https://example/xxx/[1-3].jpg -O --output-dir "C:/Brawa/xxx"
```

Note that `-O` (capital oh) is the same as `--remote-name` in the example above.

Up-to-date official `curl` binaries for Windows are available [here](https://curl.se/windows/) and option documentation for the most recent versions of `curl` is available [here](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).

---

*Note that to dynamically create folders, you can use the `--create-dirs` option to `curl` ([per the curl man page section for `--output-dir`](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--output-dir)). However, this seems to be based on the `--output-dir` option in the example above, so changing this value might require additional scripting (I was unable to get the suggestion listed in [harrymc's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1619381) to this question working correctly under Windows 7).*

Answer (score 1):

**Option values must be adjacent.** With all Unix or Unix-based programs, and most C-based ones, if you specify an option with a value, like here `-o C:/some/path`, you must keep the option 'flag' and its value together, you can't insert something else in between. In nearly all cases you can either use consecutive arguments like shown, or a *single* concatenated argument like `-oC:/some/path` (for short-form) or `--output=c:/some/path` (added equal-sign for long-form, i.e., two hyphens). This is more obvious in Windows (CMD) where you usually use `/flag:value` all run-together, which discourages you from trying to insert anything in-between.

As you commented to harrymc's answer, `--remote-name -o c:/some/path` *parses* correctly but doesn't work -- that's because these give conflicting instructions, and it obeys only the first one. `-o c:/some/path --remote-name` would also parse, but only obey the first (which if that's a file would write every URL to the same file, leaving only the last one, and if it's a directory would fail to write at all).

Aside from [Anaksunaman's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1620021/333316) you can **change the directory** to the desired location, use *only* `--remote-name` (or `-O` uppercase, either way with *no* value), then change the directory back. CMD supports `pushd` and `popd` like most Unix shells, so

```
 pushd c:\brawa\xxx & curl https://example/xxx/[1-3].jpg -O & popd
```